# No configuration helper found for: class com.ibm.ws.springboot.support.web.server.initializer.WebInitializer

Tags: spring-boot, open-liberty

I am trying to build a Spring boot project running on Liberty server. I was able to build the jar. When I am trying to start my server I am getting and error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em8sJ.png)

In build.gradle I have added

classpath 'io.openliberty.tools:liberty-gradle-plugin:3.5.2'
apply plugin: 'liberty'

I have added ServletInitializer  as per the suggestion

```
@Configuration
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(CaptchaLighweightApplication.class);
  }

}
```